# VSCODIUM cant indent html with standard tab 4spaces

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscodium

on a fresh install of **VSCodium** with extension **Prettier** on **Debian 12** I can't have a standard indent with tabs of 4 spaces on a HTML file.

(I enabled the option to **format file on save**)

On the right bottom corner of the window I chose the indent `tabs` then `4spaces`, but nothing  changes. Triggering the command `reindent file` indents just as i want (tabs of 4 spaces), but as soon as I save, it goes back to an indent of 2spaces.

Any idea will be very appreciated! Thanks

format on save option:

[image: format on save option]

inconsistent indent:

[image: inconsistent indent]

I tried onvarious html files in order to avoid any html error being responsible, but i always have the same result.

Comment: show your prettier config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure Prettier to [use tabs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tabs) [of that width](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tab-width), as it defaults to two spaces. Using an [.editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/) file is likely the simplest and most portably way to do that.